# How to select a cell in table view without scrolling it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I am building the settings screen for my app using a table VC. In the `viewDidLoad`, I want to show the user his/her current settings by selecting the cells. Then there will be a checkmark on the left of the selected cells. This is the `didSelectrowAtIndexPath` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) {
        let cellToBeDeselected = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: indexPath.section))
        cellToBeDeselected?.accessoryType = .None
    }
    cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

This works well. When I select a row, a checkmark appears. When I select another row, the previous checkmark disappears and a new one appears.

However, I want to select the rows programmatically in `viewDidLoad`, in order to show the current settings.

I found a method called `selectRowAtIndexPath`. I tried to use this but it requires a `UITableViewScrollPosition`. The docs says:

> The position in the table view (top, middle, bottom) to which a given row is scrolled.

It seems that whenever I want to select a row, the table view must scroll to where the selected row is. But I just want to select it, and *only* select it.

How to do this?

Comment: You don't have to select a cell in order to show the selection, you can do `cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` if needed.

Comment: @FahriAzimov While it may show a checkmark, the table's internal state won't have marked the cell as selected.  This could affect highlighting, or deselection from the user's point of view.

Comment: so are you trying to show only check mark in one row, based on the last setting value ?

Comment: @PetahChristian he is only trying to show a checkmark for the some settings in his app, that's it, you don't need to select a row programmatically to do that.

Comment: @Sweeper are you trying to show only check mark in one row, based on the last setting value ?

Comment: @HitendraHckr Yes I am. I am trying to show check mark in three different rows, since there are three settings

Comment: so, do you have 3 sections for different 3 settings ?

Comment: and I think any can be selected in one section, am I right ?

Comment: @HitendraHckr Yes you're right

Comment: @FahriAzimov True, but if someone else comes along and doesn't understand the ramification of only manipulating the accessory view, their code may not work properly when `indexPathForSelectedRows` returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is purely depends on the logic.

Your are trying to deselect all the rows first, when any row is selected. 
As checked your current code, found that you are not maintaining the state of selected row, so it will also cause the dequeue problem i.e. when selected cell will be reused for other cell, it will show checkMark even if that is not selected.

**Instead of this, you just need to maintain index variable which will store indexPath of selected row. You have 3 sections, and 3selections are allowed, in this case, you just need to maintain one array which holds values of selectedIndexPaths.**

**declare one property in your viewController as below.**

```
var arraySelectedIndexPaths : Array<NSIndexPath> = Array();
```

In `viewDidLoad:` add three default value as per last selected setting.

**suppose last time user have selected**

**row1 in section0**

**row2 in section1**

**row0 in section2**

then your array will be as follow,

```
        //in viewDidLoad
        arraySelectedIndexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0));
        arraySelectedIndexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 1));
        arraySelectedIndexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 2));
```

so in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` write below logic.
this logic will show checkMark in cell if it is selected, when it comes onto the screen.

```
if indexPath == self.arraySelectedIndexPaths[indexPath.section] {
   cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
}else{
   cell!.accessoryType = .None
}
```

And in `tableView:didSelectedRowAtIndexPath:` write logic as below.
This will update indexPath in array as per selection.
Will also deSelect previous row and select new row.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

//deSelected previously selected Cell
        let cellToBeDeselected = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.arraySelectedIndexPaths[indexPath.section])
        cellToBeDeselected?.accessoryType = .None

    cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    self.arraySelectedIndexPaths[indexPath.section] = indexPath;//update new selected indexPath in array
}
```

**I have wrote above logic, as per our discussion in comments for your question. below is our discussion.**

@Sweeper are you trying to show only check mark in one row, based on the last setting value ? – HitendraHckr

@HitendraHckr Yes I am. I am trying to show check mark in three different rows, since there are three settings – Sweeper

so, do you have 3 sections for different 3 settings ? – Hitendra Hckr

and I think any can be selected in one section, am I right ? – Hitendra Hckr

@HitendraHckr Yes you're right – Sweeper

Comment: Actually I am using static cells... so no `cellForRowAtIndexPath`... But anyway, it's a good answer! +1

Comment: thanks, this will work in both cases, static as well as dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:) mentions, you can specify `UITableViewScrollPositionNone` for the scroll position, which will result in no scrolling.

Comment: No. I read the docs. The `.None` option is not like that. It will still scroll. It scrolls the minimum amount to make the cell visible, right?

Comment: Did you try it?  For that particular method, it behaves differently. "Passing UITableViewScrollPositionNone results in no scrolling, rather than the minimum scrolling described for that constant."

Comment: @Sweeper Yep the documentation is wrong here. This doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly call did select method of table view using the below code

```
let indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: yourRow, inSection: yourColumn);
self.tableView(tblObj, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexpath);
```

Actually you want to call did select to perform some operation which can be manage by this. Try this, it may be work for you.

Comment: This is a delegate method which notifies your view controller when a non-programmatic selection was made.  It indicates that a selection *was* made.  Using it to "make" a selection is fragile, since you're gaming the system and circumventing the selection path provided by the system.